# Running angular2 on hostgator (or any host)

Tags: node.js, angular

I have started getting into angular2 recently and have previously used angularjs. This might seem like a very broad question but all of the tutorials show how to use angular2 on a local environment and show how to serve the app and navigate to localhost:3000 etc. So my question is how do I go about running my app on my hosted server. Like how do I get it to go to my app using www.mysite.com? Do I copy the files to my public_html directory or do I have do do something to make my domain go to the port the app is being served on? Or do I have to turn off apache and do something to use node instead? Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advice forum. You need to make an attempt and show your work so that we can help you.

Comment: I wasn't asking for advice. I am asking how to get my website to come up when going to the domain. How does my work have anything to do with that?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your project and your host. Where is the localhost:3000 coming from? Are you you running ExpressJS or angular-cli? Were you following a tutorial, etc?

Answer (score 2):

is very simple:

1. Copy local files into remote folder
2. Execute ng build --prod
3. your domain root route should be myremoteFolder/dist

hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a frontend framework, which means it runs entirely in the browser. This means it's files are "static", they don't require a web server to dynamically process the way PHP files would. This means they can be hosted anywhere static files can be hosted such as AWS S3 or whatever directory you'd put your images and stylesheets on HostGator.

I'm assuming the `localhost:3000` is a simple development server used for local testing. If it does more work than that, such as expose API endpoints that your Angular app calls to, then you'll need to find a host that can run NodeJS applications.